# Porque sucede este problema con el promedio?

Tags: c++, funciones, matrices

Estoy realizando un programa el cual me están exigiendo un procedimiento, que calcule, a través de una función la nota de determinados estudiantes la cual el usuario las coloco anteriormente y estas se almacenaron en una matriz.

De esa matriz tengo que sacarle el promedio a la filas ya que se supone que las filas de las matriz representa las notas de cada estudiante.

Cuando llamo la función me da un resultado erróneo y no me saca el promedio, realmente nose que estaré haciendo mal.

Aquí dejo el código para que lo puedan comprobar:

```
using namespace std;

int nota[10][6];
int f, c, es=1;
float suma=0;
float acumuladorfila=0;
float promedionota=0;

float promedio (float notas=0, float num=5){
    return notas / num;
}
    
    
void matriz(){
        
    for (f=0;f<10;f++)
    {
        printf("\n\tESTUDIANTE %d:  ",f+1);
        
        for (c=0;c<5;c++)
        {
            printf("\nIndique la nota de la asignatura %d:  ", c+1);
            scanf("%d", &nota [f][c]);
            es++;
        }
        
    }
    
}
    
void mostrarmatriz(){
    
    printf("\n\n\tEst\tAs1\tAs2\tAs3\tAs4\tAs5");
    printf("\n\t===\t===\t===\t===\t===\t====");
    
    for (f=0;f<10;f++)
    {
        printf ("\n\t %d",f+1);
        
        for (c=0;c<5;c++)
        {
            cout<<"\t"<<nota [f][c];
        }
            
        cout<<endl;
    }
        
}
    
            
void calcularpromedio(){
    
    for (c=0;c<5;c++){
        acumuladorfila= acumuladorfila+nota[f][c];
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 1 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 2 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 3 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 4 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 5 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 6 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 7 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 8 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 9 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"El promedio de las notas del estudiante 10 "<<"es de:     "<<promedio(acumuladorfila,c);
}

int main(){
    
    matriz();
    
    mostrarmatriz();
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    calcularpromedio();

    return 0;
```

Aún no esta terminado pero me falta sacar el promedio.

Comment: El diseño del programa es mejorable. Muchas de las variables que declaras como globales deberían ser locales de las funciones, y otras deberían ser parámetros de las funciones. De todas formas, el error más evidente que observo, es que no inicializas `acumuladorfila` con 0 antes de sumarle todos los elementos, y que el valor de ese acumulador no depende del alumno, es el mismo para todos los alumnos (y ¿qué hace el bucle en `f` cuyo cuerpo está vacío? No hace nada)

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y no entiendo mucho, la verdad he hecho lo que puedo y solo me falta sacar el promedio de los estudiantes para terminar el ejercicio, me pudiera explicar un poco mejor para  poder captarle la idea?, y disculpe!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si yo te digo:

- Calcúlame el promedio.

Tu respuesta debería ser:

- Que te calcule el promedio ¿de qué?

---

Y eso es lo que tienes:

- `void calcularpromedio()`
- Que te calcule el promedio ¿de qué?

---

Haz que la función reciba una colección de datos a promediar y devuelva dicho promedio:

```
float calcularPromedio(float *notas, int cantidad)
{
    float total = .0f;
    for (int indice = 0; indice != cantidad; ++indice)
        total += notas[indice];

    return total / cantidad;
}
```